# Hibernate Simple JoinTable Without Using Entity

Tags: hibernate, join

I am trying to run a simple JoinTable operation in Hibernate and it is giving me fits.  I have one table that represents an entity called "Person".  I have another table that represents social security numbers (for example).  I want to have social security number as a String (it is VARCHAR2) be a property on the PersonEntity.  PersonEntity works just fine without the following code.  Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
@JoinTable(name = "PERSON_ID_X_SSN", 
               joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")})
    @Column(name="SSN", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private String social;
```

The PERSON_ID_X_SSN table is simple this:

```
PERSON_ID, SSN
```

Everything works great without this code.  As soon as I add it in the entire entity is null.  I would prefer not to make a separate entity for PERSON_ID_X_SSN...  please help!  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JoinTable is for specifying table that is used to persist relationships between entities.

In this case there is no relationship between entities, but one entity that should be persisted to two tables. [@SecondaryTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html) is annotation that servers this purpose. Idea is to specify secondary table (or more than one via @SecondaryTables) for entity and explicitly mention name of table in @Column annotation when table other than primary should be used to persist attribute.

In your case something like following will work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
@SecondaryTable(
  name="PERSON_ID_X_SSN", 
  pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID"))
public class Person {
  @Column(table="PERSON_ID_X_SSN", name="SSN")
  private String social;
  ...
}
```

}